# Calling external jQuery functions w/o document.ready();

Tags: jquery

Kinda new to jQuery and looking for help on how to keep all my script in one external file and not have it all be nested in document.ready();. I'm hoping to be able to call certain functions from specific pages only and have the rest be handle with ready();. I'm not 100% sure what the best practice is to call a function from a page either :/
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When the DOM is ready, you can do whatever. And?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having multiple document.readys

I like to add a unique ID to each page, and have the javascript check that the ID exists before executing. You can create a simple wrapper function that does the check AND waits for document.ready:

```
var pageReady = function (id, callback) {
   $(function () {
      if ($(id).length) {
         callback();
      }
   });
};
```

Then, similar to document.ready, you can have:

```
pageReady("#home-page", function () {
   // Code will only run for home page here
});

pageReady("#search-page", function () {
   // Code will only run for search page here
});
```

Just remember to add the IDs...

```
<body id="home-page">
```

Comment: This approach seems to work for my application. It appears I can keep all my functions nested in a document.ready(); and use the var pageReady to call the functions that are needed on those pages.

Comment: @geraddavivs, just be careful about putting all of your function is a document.ready if you are concerned about performance http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Comment: This is useful (and works), if you don't want to have JS in the view (only in site.js for minifying). But one question: The main function is called by every page load (also for all other pages)... What about performance..?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep all of your scripts in a single file if you like. You can have your plain JS functions in the file and not inside the document.ready() function if you don't need to manipulate or interact with the DOM. You can then put all of your DOM manipulation and interaction JS inside of the document.ready() function. You can also put JS in a $(window).load() function to run code once all of the resource have loaded on the page including images.

**Example:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // code that will run once all resources and the DOM are loaded into the browser
  console.log("window loaded");
});

runOnScriptLoad();
function runOnScriptLoad() {
  // code that will run as soon as the JS file loads
  console.log("script loaded");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // code that will run once the entire DOM is loaded into the browser
  console.log("DOM ready");
});

$(window).load(function() {
  // code that will run once all resources and the DOM are loaded into the browser
  console.log("window loaded");
});
```

**Example Page:** => http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/forums/stack-overflow/example-dom-ready.html

Have your firebug console open when you load the page and you will see the order in which each get executed in.

Comment: @Alex why? There are only specific situations where this is useful since it is slower than document ready.

Comment: @box9 for those specific situations. And the difference in speed isn't *huge*.

Comment: @box9 @Alex, The difference is completely dependent on the size of the resources and the speed of the internet connection over which those resources are being retrieved. I don't remember what the situation was but there was one time when I had to use the $(window).load() and it saved me. Other than that, I have never had a need for it but thought it would be good to share.

Comment: @Alex @Mike Grace I've never needed to use .load() so I'm just curious to know what practical scenarios require it.

Comment: There is a really good argument for using .load at http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/ on #9

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple dom readys.

One of my favourite ways to determine if I should run some code on a page is to give the body a uniquie class, and then use this...

```
if ($('body').hasClass('contact')) {
   // Validate form, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

In your external file you can have `$(document).ready(function () { //code here; });` Alternatively, you can have all your functions in the external file, and then just on your page have

```
$(document).ready(function () { myfunction(); });
```